# Error not found when i call my rest service

Tags: java, rest, url

I'm trying to call a rest service specifically get but when I type the URL it gives me not found, I have already set up a web service soap in this maven project and it works for me by any chance am I missing some dependency or error in the web file?

My url: http://localhost:8080/ProvaMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/getuser

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenRest</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProvaMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
        
  <dependencies>          
      
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.jws/jakarta.jws-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>
    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>    
      
  </dependencies>
       
    <build>
      
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>19</source>
                <target>19</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>    

  </build>
              
</project>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
  <display-name>ProvaMaven</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
              
</web-app>
```

Here is my class:

```
package com;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET; 
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/rest")
public class Rest
{
    @GET
    @Path("/getuser")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUser()
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.setName("carmine");
        u.setSurname("armenante");
        
        System.out.println("sono dentro");
        return u;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:8080/rest/getuser instead of
http://localhost:8080/ProvaMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/getuser
Don't need ProvaMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: i have already try it but not working

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an additional /rest try this http://localhost:8080/rest/rest/getuser

Comment: where is the additional rest?

Comment: Hello sorry try http://localhost:8080/ProvaMaven/rest/getuser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).